# Combine Migration?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

How to replace closure or delegation callback which get called when user tap on a button of a table view cell with **Combine framework** ?

problem - if Subscriber is added from the view controller and store returned AnyCancellable in a Set ; 1. storage of anyCancellable is getting heigh as cell return .2. many subscribers receive value when user tap on one button of a cell

I used built in subscriber **Sink**

**In ViewController**

```
 var myAnyCancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell")
        cell.doSomethingSubject.sink { 
print("user tap button on cell")
                            }.store(in: &myAnyCancellableSet)
        return cell
                    }
```

**In tableview cell**

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
   
    private lazy var myDoSomethingSubject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
    lazy var doSomethingSubject = myDoSomethingSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    
   @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        myDoSomethingSubject.send()
    }

}
```

Comment: It's unclear (to me, at least) what you're asking. Can you share some code of either what you have (and want to change) or what you've tried

Comment: @NewDev  Old way - we use delegation pattern to notify from viewCotroller, when user taps button in tableViewcell.                                                                                             Combine- ?                                                                                                                          I need to get done just this work using Apples Combine framework .

Comment: All I'm saying is code speaks volume... I suggest you take the time to edit your question with some code to illustrate the problem

Comment: @NewDev i added

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't store all your tickets together. Store them by index path.

```
var ticketForIndexPath: [IndexPath: AnyCancellable] = [:]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell") as! MyCell
    ticketForIndexPath[indexPath] = cell.doSomethingSubject.sink {
        print("user tap button on cell")
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    ticketForIndexPath[indexPath] = nil
}
```

Comment: is there any best way to handle this using combine other than adding subscriber when cell is returned ?

Comment: cause delegating pattern or closure looks like easy... other than we cant get error and success completing  vale separately .